# How to allow extraction of real time data from Unity game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building a game in Unity and want to allow 3rd parties to access game variables in real-time.

For example, the game will maintain the position of the player in its internal state, but I want to have a way to expose that variable so that 3rd party programs running alongside the game can read it and do what they like with it - for example, draw a plot of where the player has been.

One possible way of doing this would be to effectively have my game run a localhost only webserver, create a REST API and then 3rd party programs could make HTTP requests to localhost and get my game state from it.

However:

1. I've no idea how I could even do that.
2. That seems like vastly over engineering.

So, is there a sensible / easy way of exposing internal game data to arbitrary other programs?

Comment: You could just write these datas to a file every so often, and let other applications read this file?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.